# Call function declared in external file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript file called "menuTree.ts" which is compiled to the following Javascript code:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var MenuTree = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MenuTree() {
    }
    MenuTree.prototype.refreshTree = function (bereichId, page) {
        var _this = this;
    };
    return MenuTree;
}());
exports.MenuTree = MenuTree;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=menuTree.js.map
```

This JavaScript code is placed in a separate JavaScript file which is placed in the head-section of my web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="menuTree" src="http://localhost:65013//Assets/Scripts/Javascript/menuTree.js"></script>
```

Now further down below in the body section I would like to call the "refreshTree" function when clicking on an anchor:

```
<a onclick='javascript: return refreshTree(1, 2)'>Refresh</a>
```

But I always get the error message that refreshTree is not defined. I also tried it with MenuTree.refreshTree(1,2) but without success.

Any help is very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For one thing, `MenuTree` is a class, so you'd have to do `new MenuTree().refreshTree(1, 2)`.  You'll also need to `require` it.  So try `<a onlick='new (require("menuTree").MenuTree)().refreshTree(1, 2)'>Refresh</a>` and let me know how far you get.

Comment: Thanks for your help Matt. Now I get the message "Error: Module name "menuTree" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])".

Comment: It looks like your `menuTree` module isn't loading properly.  For me to be able to investigate further, you'll need to publish a repository that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Works now, thanks for your help! Would you mind to post your comment as answer so I can accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, `MenuTree` is a class, so you'd have to do `new MenuTree().refreshTree(1, 2)`. You'll also need to `require` it. So try:

```
<a onlick='new (require("menuTree").MenuTree)().refreshTree(1, 2)'>Refresh</a>
```

(Based on the comment thread, it looks like additional steps may have been needed to resolve the problem, but I don't know what they were.)